# Amazon S3 basic action doesn't work

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pear, vagrant

I'm trying to use Amazon S3 to store my images.
What I've done so far is installing the AWS SDK via PEAR (link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html)

Then I've gone to the second step, creating a client:

```
<?php

// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials and desired AWS region
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'your-aws-access-key-id',
    'secret' => 'your-aws-secret-access-key',
));
```

My keys are set correctly ... .

Then I want to test all this by creating a bucket like this:

```
$bucket = 'my-bucket';
try{
    $result = $client->createBucket(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ));

    // Wait until the bucket is created
    $client->waitUntil('BucketExists', array('Bucket' => $bucket));
}
catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

But I always get this error:

> The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.

I think my SDK isn't properly installed ... Can anyone help me with this? I'm using vagrant so I installed the AWS SDK in my root folder with this command:

> sudo pear -D auto_discover=1 install pear.amazonwebservices.com/sdk

I got the message that is was installed ok.

I've also did a var_dump of my $client. The link to my response: http://pastebin.com/KqkEiKGs
Don't now if you're something with it ... (My keys are hidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message says it - you are trying to use the name that is not unique for your bucket, you should use some more unique names. And, yes, bucket names must be **unique across all of Amazon S3** (not only your account).

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html).